# How to solve this propositional logic propblems using the following rules.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Okay so I have the following problem, which I need to solve without using truth tables.

This is the formula

```
p ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ≡ p ∧ q
```

and these are the semantic equivalences, which I have to use

```
A ∧ A ≡ A, A ∨ A ≡ A                                      idempotence

A ∧ B ≡ B ∧ A, A ∨ B ≡ B ∨ A                              commutativity

A ∧ (B ∧ C ) ≡ (A ∧ B) ∧ C , A ∨ (B ∨ C ) ≡ (A ∨ B) ∨ C   associativity

A ∧ (A ∨ B) ≡ A, A ∨ (A ∧ B) ≡ A                           absorption

A ∧ (B ∨ C ) ≡ (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ C )                         distributivity

A ∨ (B ∧ C ) ≡ (A ∨ B) ∧ (A ∨ C )                         distributivity

A ∧ (¬A) ≡ false, A ∨ (¬A) ≡ true                          negation

¬(¬A) ≡ A                                                  double negation

¬(A ∧ B) ≡ (¬A) ∨ (¬B), ¬(A ∨ B) ≡ (¬A) ∧ (¬B)             de Morgan

A ⇒ B ≡ (¬A) ∨ B                                          implication

A ⇔ B ≡ (A ⇒ B) ∧ (B ⇒ A)                                bi-implication
```

Answer (score 1):

Try applying distributivity to $p \wedge (\neg p \vee q)$, then go from there.

Comment: yeah that is the first step I have already done. I was thinking of doing the implication rule which would turn it into (p -> p) v (p ∧ q) but kind of stuck after that

Comment: @user5647516 What statement do you get after distributing?

Comment: I get (p ∧ ¬p ) v (p ∧ q) @DylanSp

Comment: @user5647516 And what can you do with the $p \wedge \neg p$ term?

Comment: make it false so i end up with false v (p ∧ q) @DylanSp

Comment: @DanSimon what do you think of this one?

Comment: So here's the thing; (false) $ \vee S \equiv S$ for any statement S. However, this isn't listed in the supplied rules, so I'm not sure how you should proceed.

Comment: @user5647516 Use Negation again: $$\textsf{false}\vee (p\wedge q) \equiv ((p\wedge q) \wedge\neg(p\wedge q) )\vee (p\wedge q) $$ Follow with Associativity, then Absorption.